# P2P for chat and/or broadcasting messages

Tags: messaging, p2p, broadcast, dht

So basically I want to be write a P2P-software that is able to send text messages to all nodes, kind of like IRC. What kind of network am I adviced to use? I've looked some into DHT Kademlia, and it seems easy enough to implement, but it doesn't appear to be useful for what I want to do? What kind of protocol does Skype, for example, use?

edit: and I forgot to mention, it doesn't have to be instant messaging, a latency of several minutes is more than acceptable. I don't suppose I could continously try getting the data corresponding to the to the current time every five minutes or something on all nodes?

Comment: If it's possible to do it with DHT that'd be preferable since it seems to be the most commonly implemented type, and thus has more documentation. If possible, how would it be done?

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of network am I adviced to use?

If Java is an option for you, then you should investigate [JXTA](http://jxse.kenai.com) and propagated messages.

> I've looked some into DHT Kademlia, and it seems easy enough to implement, but it doesn't appear to be useful for what I want to do?

DHT tells you where your information is (i.e. which node), but doesn't tell you how to access it and transfer it. The latter issue is pretty technical and involves NAT traversal and TURN or STUNT P2P implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You say "all nodes".

If you want broadcast functionality i'd suggest using Freepastry. Have a look at the scribe tutorial here. https://trac.freepastry.org/wiki/tut_scribe

I've used free pastry as a file sharing application and have done quite a bit of performance testing. It's very easy to implement and is very reliable. Works great in my experience.

Comment: Hello... You have done it in android or JAVA? i am trying to implement the same in android, in java it's wrking fine but creating problem in Android.